# Декомпилиция jar файла

Tags: java, java-me

Интересует, чем можно наиболее точно декомпилировать jar файл, чтобы потом его можно было откомпилировать (есть что-нибудь лучше чем jd)?

Comment: Чем jad не устроил?
Вас забанили в гугле?

Comment: Если код был обфусцирован, то ни один декомпилятор в удобочитаемый вид его не приведет.

Comment: Если хорошо умеете рыться в гугле зачем зарегистрировались тут?

Comment: Кроме jd есть чтото лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jar файл это обычный архив. скорее всего у вас проблема с декомпилированием обфусцированых классов.

вам следует разобратся с форматом class файла, и для каждого изменить секцию в которой описываются имена классов, методов и переменных 
(обычно обфускатор делает их всех одинаковыми напр "a"). после этого декомпилируете без проблем любым декомпилером